# Displaying a "smart" search box in your website's header

Tags: magento-2.1, search, catalogsearch

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop. To achieve this, I have created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

I have installed and enabled the [Magento 2.0 SmartSearch](https://github.com/Sebwite/Magento2-SmartSearch) and I want to display the search bar, which *currently does not display anywhere*, above the top links, like the screenshot indicates:

[image]

In `app/code/Sebwite/SmartSearch/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` I have added this line `<move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" before="top.links"/>`:

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
  <referenceBlock name="top.search">
    <arguments>
      <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Sebwite/SmartSeach/templates/form.mini.phtml</argument>
    </arguments>
  </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
<move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" before="top.links"/>
```

But no change occurred.

Inside the same file, the logo blook looks like this:

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container" htmlId="siteHeader" htmlClass="panel wrapper fullwidth">
  <container name="header-wrapper" label="Page Header" as="header-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content">
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo">
      <arguments>
        <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo.png</argument>
        <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">263</argument>
        <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">85</argument>
      </arguments>
    </block>
  </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Is there anything I can add to it to display the search box, who's template is `app/code/Sebwite/SmartSearch/view/frontend/templates/form.mini.phtml` inside the logo block? I would then only have to float it right.

Comment: looking into the code of the module sebwite, they have setup the form.mini.phtml file (https://github.com/Sebwite/Magento2-SmartSearch/blob/master/view/frontend/templates/form.mini.phtml). can you please check if this file is rendering on the website header?

Comment: adding to the previous message, best way is to modify the the code.

Comment: How? In what way?

Comment: I need to move that code after the logo. It is _not_ even visible in the source.
 What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

can you make sure module is enabled and you did setup upgrade?

https://github.com/Sebwite/Magento2-SmartSearch

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

can you send link here to see output?

Comment: Yes I did all that.