# Magento 2.1 error: Class Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Search does not exist

Tags: magento-2.1, search, catalogsearch

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop. To achieve this, I have created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

I want to display the *search bar* above the top links, at the right of the logo:

[image]

For this purpose, I wrote the line below, in my `default.xml` file:

```
<move element="top.links" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />
<move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" before="top.links"/>

<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
  <block name="panel.top.links" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" after="-">
    <arguments>
      <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
    </arguments>
  </block>
</referenceContainer>

<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
  <block name="panel.top.search" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Search" after="-">
    <arguments>
      <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header search</argument>
    </arguments>
  </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

The `<block name="panel.top.search" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Search" after="-">` part produces the error: *Class Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Search does not exist* in the browser.

As you can see, on the **[website's homepage](https://staging.pro-detailing.ro/)**, the search box does not appear anywhere.

What am I doing wrong? How shall I change my code to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that **Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Search** doesn't exists and you can't use class attribute for block node in layout xml file with value of not exist class. Search form already added in block with **top.search** name.

You can see how it added in magento's module-search default.xml layout file:

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
```

So I think that move instruction will be enough just to move exist search block and not to create new one

Comment: I have installed and enabled the [Magento 2.0 SmartSearch](https://github.com/Sebwite/Magento2-SmartSearch) so this may be the reason tour code does not work. Otherwise, it looks valid. Please, have a look at **[Displaying a “smart” search box in your website's header](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/207298/displaying-a-smart-search-box-in-your-websites-header)**. Thanks!

Comment: Is `form.mini.phtml` the *only* template for the search box?

Comment: In what directory should the `form.mini.phtml` be for the code to work (it might be missing for my Magento instance)?